# How to async join tables in RavenDB

Tags: asynchronous, join, ravendb, raven

I need to do query from two raven db tables.
I found almoust perfect solution in documentation, only problem is im using async session and have no idea what is async equivalent.

```
var q = from order in dq
let company = session.Load<Company>(order.Company)
select new
{
    order.Freight,
    company.Name
    
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:
`RavenQuery.Load<Company>(order.Company)`

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/indexes/querying/projections#example-viii---projection-using-a-loaded-document